# React - How can I make a component from a function inside a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

New to React - I have a component AddForm that looks like this:

```
class AddForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    };
  }

  handleInput = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  logValue = () => {
    console.log(this.state.name)
    return <Display text={this.state.name} />
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput}
          placeholder="Type Here" type="text" />
        <button onClick={this.logValue}
          type="submit">Submit</button>        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And when the user clicks on the "Submit" button I want it to display what was in the form. I stored the value in form in this.state.name and my component for displaying the text inside of the form looks like this:

```
class Display extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

I know that I the state.name can access the form because I console.logged it. I just want to know why my return statement in the logValue function in the AddForm component isn't creating a new component, Display, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The click of the button should result in a state change that the render method then uses to return the Display component - something like:

```
logValue = () => {
  this.setState({ showingName: !this.state.showingName });
}
```

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.showingName ? <Display text={this.state.name} /> : null
      }
      <input onChange={this.handleInput}
        placeholder="Type Here" type="text" />
      <button onClick={this.logValue}
        type="submit">Submit</button>        
    </div>
  )
}
```